# Can't read JSON data correctly by $.each jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to use `$.getJSON` to get data from the NHTSA recall API and append the `Component` object from the `Results` array to a `div` with the `id="data"`. Here is the URL I am trying to get JSON for:
http://www.nhtsa.gov/webapi/api/Recalls/vehicle/modelyear/2000/make/honda/model/accord?format=json

Here is the snippet that I am using:

`var url = 'http://www.nhtsa.gov/webapi/api/Recalls/vehicle/modelyear/2000/make/honda/model/accord?format=json';

```
$.getJSON( url, function(data) {
    console.log(data.Results);        

    $.each(data.Results, function(i,Results){
        var component = this.Component;

        $('#data').append('<h4>' +component+ '</h4>');
    }
}
```

I have used this similar format for a few other API's and it worked so I am not sure why the call isn't going through.

Comment: Using `this.Component;` inside a callback will require a bind.  And it is not clear how `Results` are used in the `append`.

Comment: You have not described what the problem is. Are you getting an error in your iteration? Or is the call not going through?

Comment: Sorry about that. The call just isn't going through @praneetloke

Comment: @James "The call just isn't going through" is not a description of a problem. Explain the actual behavior, versus expected behavior, and any error messages.  What did your `console.log` output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a cross origin request problem using $.getJSON (as I often do), so I tried jsonp and succeeded. Please give it a try and let me know if you have questions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var http = 'http://www.nhtsa.gov/webapi/api/Recalls/vehicle/modelyear/2000/make/honda/model/accord?format=json';
    $.ajax({
        url: http,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            var div = $('#data');
            for(var i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
                $(div).append('<div>' + data.Results[i].Component + '</div>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
```